# Is there a way to show all views that contain a certain row in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a spreadsheet that contains lots and lots of views with various filters, and I would like to be able to select a row and see a list of all the views that contain that row. Is this possible in google sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to discover which [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) would show a particular row.

Nevertheless, filter views must use some *criteria* to decide whether a row should be hidden or remain visible. If you have access to those criteria, you can apply the same or similar criteria in a formula to find whether a row fulfills those criteria or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do have access to the criteria so I may give this a try